# Seeking recommendations for a funnel graph component

Tags: php, javascript, graph

I would like to generate funnel chart on my web page. I am using Google Graph for all graphs, but it seems funnel type is not supported by it.

So what now? Could you please recommend any non-flash alternative for Google Graph which could works with funnel type as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just looking around myself and found:

http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#funnel-chart

One drawback is that the free version only renders in Flash and the paid version is $399 for a single license!

A free library http://www.jqplot.com/ seems to handle funnels in JS. eg:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    s1 = [['Sony',7], ['Samsumg',13.3], ['LG',14.7], ['Vizio',5.2], ['Insignia', 1.2]];

    plot4 = $.jqplot('chart4', [s1], {
        seriesDefaults:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.FunnelRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                showDataLabels: true,
                dataLabels: ['47 years', '28 years', '22 years', '14 years', '7 years']
            }
        },
        legend: {
            show: true,
            placement: 'outside'
        }
    });
});
```

Other people have "hacked" together a "solution" in google charts by centering a bar chart: [Centered bars on a Google Chart BarChart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585495/centered-bars-on-a-google-chart-barchart)