# Trying to make a funnel visualization in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I'm building a reporting dashboard in Google sheets for a website. Our website has a subscription funnel that I'd like to visualize.
Since Google Sheets has no built in funnel visualization I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585495/centered-bars-on-a-google-chart-barchart) SO post which suggests using a stacked bar chart and making one of the series' white. Here is the result:

[image]

So this kind of works except, after fiddling with the advanced edit options:

1. I cannot remove the border
2. I cannot remove the left vertical line

Searching Google this appears to be true - [there is currently no way to remove the border on a GSheet chart](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/IXXWjEcCxxU).

I've been waiting for a suitable task to grab the bull by the horns with creating custom charts and scripts within GSheets using Google-Apps-Script and Google-Charts-Api. I have some foundational skills with Javascript and use it on a regular basic, but lightly.

My question is this. Is what I'm trying to achieve possible if I was to code the visualization using apps script and charts API, as opposed to just using the built in chart functionality?

Is the route I'm taking the only one or the "best" one given my goal of creating a funnel chart?

I almost have what I need if I could only hide the border and left vertical line but, pedantic as it may sound, I am not going to use the visualization in my dashboard if I cannot find a way to hide them.

Any help or pointers appreciated.